# Initializate float4x4 in vertex shader

Tags: c++, directx, directx11

Forgive me for my English. I am trying to create a 4x4 matrix in vertex shader, but it is not initialized correctly. Why is this happening?
Vertex shader:

```
struct LogicBufferPosition
{
    matrix Pos;
};

struct LogicBufferBool
{
    bool flag;
};

StructuredBuffer<LogicBufferPosition> arrayPositions: register(t0);
StructuredBuffer<LogicBufferBool> arrayBools: register(t1);

cbuffer ConstantBufferVS: register(b0)
{ 
    matrix World; 
    matrix View; 
    matrix Perspective; 
}; 

struct VS_INPUT 
{ 
    float3 Pos: POSITION; 
    float3 TexCoord: TEXCOORD;
    float3 Normal: NORMAL;
}; 

struct GS_INPUT
{ 
    float4 Pos: SV_POSITION; 
    float3 TexCoord: TEXCOORD0;
    float3 Normal: TEXCOORD1;
    bool visible: VISIBLE_FLAG; // отрисовывать ли примитив?
};

GS_INPUT main(VS_INPUT input, uint id: SV_InstanceID) 
{ 
    GS_INPUT _out = (GS_INPUT)0; 
    if(arrayBools[id].flag == false)
    {
        _out.visible = arrayBools[id].flag;
        return _out;
    }


    float4x4 translateCenter = 
    {
    1.f,0.f,0.f,-input.Pos.x,
    0.f,1.f,0.f,-input.Pos.y, 
    0.f,0.f,1.f,-input.Pos.z,
    0.f,0.f,0.f,1.f,
    };

    float4x4 translateCenterInverse = 
    {
    1,0,0,input.Pos.x,
    0,1,0,input.Pos.x,
    0,0,1,input.Pos.x,
    0,0,0,1
    };


    _out.Pos = mul(float4(input.Pos, 1), World); 
    _out.Pos = mul(_out.Pos, translateCenter);
    _out.Pos = mul(_out.Pos, arrayPositions[id].Pos);
    _out.Pos = mul(_out.Pos, translateCenterInverse);

    _out.Pos = mul(_out.Pos, View); 
    _out.Pos = mul(_out.Pos, Perspective); 
    _out.TexCoord = input.TexCoord;
    _out.Normal = input.Normal;
    _out.visible = arrayBools[id].flag;
    return _out; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: The most common issue is that your C++ code likely uses row-major matrices, while HLSL shaders default to column-major matrices. This means you typically need to Transpose your matrix as you set it into the constant buffer. See [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-per-component-math#matrix-ordering).

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn All matrices that are sent to the shader are transposed. The problem is in the matrices created in the shader itself. look at the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. I thought that the matrix by columns is filled as I showed above. And it should be in the usual way:

```
float4x4 translateCenter = 
{
1.f,0.f,0.f,0.f,
0.f,1.f,0.f,0.f, 
0.f,0.f,1.f,0.f,
-center.x,-center.y,-center.z,1.f
};

float4x4 translateCenterInverse = 
{
1.f,0.f,0.f,0.f,
0.f,1.f,0.f,0.f,
0.f,0.f,1.f,0.f,
center.x,center.y,center.z,1.f
};
```